# Vim for VSCode does not work correctly occasionally for moving cursor to previous or next position (ctrl + i / o)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

One of my most beloved features in Vim is using `ctrl + o` for moving to recent previous positions, and `ctrl + i` to restore (moving forward) the cursor.

For some reason in my VSCode this would not work correctly all the time. Sometimes the cursor jumps to a totally wrong position, that I might have visited before, but seems totally random.

I'm wondering does anyone else have experienced this before, is this maybe a setting? I'm running on `vscodevim 1.23.2` which seems to be the latest.

Thank you

Comment: have you filed an issue at the extension repo

Comment: @rioV8 not yet.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone coming across this, this seems to be a known problem discussed in the issues section of the [repo](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/5127)

One possible workaround is to override the keybindings to use VSCodes own going `forward`/`backward` by this keybinding:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+o",
    "command": "workbench.action.navigateBack"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+i",
    "command": "workbench.action.navigateForward"
},
```

this works well after a short testing.

Comment: Interesting, I just added this to keybindings.json and it switches between vs code tabs rather than jumping back to the last cursor spot